# Select all tables having a class jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried:

```
 $("table .person-row")
```

But this selected all elements under all table with the class person-row.

I just need to select all table with class person-row.

Comment: Read up on [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors). That should help.

Comment: Your expression is selecting table's children with class "person-row"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("table.person-row")
```

No spaces needed between the table and the class name with `.`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have tried the code which returns the union. But you need the intersection of it, for that just write the selectors together without spaces in between.

```
$("table.person-row")
```

**UPDATE:**

Reference link: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: @user444569: i have updated the reference link. you can find it in api.jquery.com itself

Answer (score 0):

you can even mention the exact hierarchy. like the parent div id . remove space before the class name with .

for eg : div->table->.person-row

```
$("#YourParentDiv table.person-row")
```